# Getting random substitutes of a single column variable Rstudio

Tags: r, grouping, sample

I have an excell file containing 500 words in 1 column. I want to create 100 groups of 5 random words existing in this column without any duplicates. So every word should just occur once. In Rstudio I managed to get a single sample (sample_n(df, 5)) but this only yields one output.

How can I make this work for 100 groups?

```
x <- as.data.frame(c("Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Orange", "Melon", "Mango"))
sample_n(x, 2)
```

The output just gives me 1 group of 2 fruits but instead I want 3 distinct groups of 2 fruits.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way to do it, by creating a dataframe. Each group is one row.

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- data.frame(var = c("Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Orange", "Melon", "Mango")) %>%
  pull(var) %>%
  sample() %>% 
  matrix(ncol = 2) %>%
  data.frame()


#     X1     X2
#1  Pear  Mango
#2 Apple Orange
#3 Melon Banana
```

For your project you may set the `ncol` argument to 5.